# How to get the right revcounter through Django Pagnination?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list of users. I list them in page with pagination like the following

```
113 - User13
112 - User 12
```

The problem is that each page is initializing with the the quantity set to the pagination. Let's say I have set a pagination with 10 users. each page will be set with the same counter like:

```
10 - user10
9 - user
8 - user1
```

I have tried this, but it's not working.

```
 {{forloop.revcounter0|all_profiles.end_index}} - {{user.get_full_name}}
```

What I want is, with for instance 6 users divided by 2 pages with a pagination set to 3 users. **Note the correct counter**

Page 1

```
6.- User 6
5.- User 5
4.- User 4
```

Page 2

```
3.- User 3
2.- User 2
1.- User 1
```

Comment: Can't you use Django's pagination start_index() and end_index() ?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/

Comment: I did, but it refused to show the correct counter for each page.

Comment: Show what you tried

Comment: Here it is `{{forloop.revcounter0|all_profiles.end_index}} - {{user.get_full_name}}`

Comment: Then you haven't tried something with Django pagination which is what I suggested